# InApp - This version of application is not configured for billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, apk, in-app-billing

Alright, before you all flame at me that it is a duplicate, I have already tried all of the other answers around the internet and I'm still getting this error.
Note: I'm using the in-app V3 API.

1. First, I created the in-app product (I already had an apk draft file in my console).
2. Tested my app with the `android.test.purchased` SKU, it works just fine, and changed the SKU back to my in-app original SKU.
3. I have created my signed apk using the Export wizard of Eclipse.
4. Succefully uploaded the signed apk file to my Android Console Developer Account.
5. Sent the signed apk file over gmail and installed the signed apk file on my device from my gmail account.
6. Waited for about `10 hours` (went to sleep).
7. Getting up, trying to use the in-app purchase and seeing that error.

I have already checked that the version name, version code are equal on device and google play. They are the same. What am I missing here?

> This version of application is not configured for billing.

Comment: Have you got it solved?

Comment: Same here, no idea what do anymore. The new Android console is very buggy it seems

Comment: @Gerard My app is already published, and the in-app is working just fine now. I'm not sure if it works because I have changed anything or maybe because I have just published it via the Developer Console. I guess you should just publish and see how it goes. You can always update your app.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I did as well and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You must publish your new app version if you want to execute a *real* payment. Only test payments can be executed on a not published version.

Comment: According to this article : http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html#PlayItemTest It is not true, I don't have to publish my app in order to test my products. It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I mean that I don't really want to execute a real payment, but a test payment with my real SKU item that exists in my Android Console Developer.

Comment: It's true, you should be able to do an actual payment as long as the account used is a test account, but it's bugged as hell, I also get this false not eligible notification.